# ASP.NET Core 3.1: Why can't I get Access Token?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-3.1

I am able to get id_token but I get null when I try to get access token. And I can't figure out why?

[image]

```
var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken); // token has value
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);// accessToken is null
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var jwtTokenConfig = Configuration.GetSection("jwtTokenConfig").Get<JwtTokenConfig>();
        services.AddSingleton(jwtTokenConfig);
        services.AddSingleton<IJwtAuthManager, JwtAuthManager>();
        services.AddHostedService<JwtRefreshTokenCache>();
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
                CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
            options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
                CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {

            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
        
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            

            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("intercepted");
            };
        });

    


        var azureAd = new AzureAd();
        Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(azureAd);
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

     
        var url = "https://localhost:5001/platform/signin-oidc";

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {

                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = url;

                    //context.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code, see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1452).

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken)
```

And we usually authorize by Azure AD following this sample: https://github.com/AzureAdQuickstarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

Comment: InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.External'. The registered schemes are: AzureAD, AzureADOpenID, AzureADCookie. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Identity.External",...)?

Comment: Hi, @SamuraiJack. Please share your code about how you set the AAD configuration. And which API you want to request?